# Stop tocbind from adding table of contents to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using `tocbibind` to add my bibliography to my TOC. However, `tocbibind` also adds the table of contents to the table of contents. How can I prevent this? Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter title}
Some text.

\chapter{Another one}
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `[nottoc]` option.

Comment: That works. Happy to accept it as an answer if you're so inclined.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it's necessary – I'm sure someone already made such an answer.